# SpringBoot ElasticsearchRepository: search_context_missing_exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Let's say that we have this ElasticsearchRepository in a SpringBoot app:

```
interface TransactionsRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Transaction, String> {
    Stream<Transaction> findAllBySomething(String something);
}
```

If I have too many records to fetch after 105 seconds the call fails with the error:

> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception
> [type=search_context_missing_exception, reason=No search context found
> for id [44763]]
> Blockquote

What do I need to configure to increase the Scroll API time, so I don't get this error anymore? Or what are the solutions when you have >10,000 records to fetch?

I don't know if this is set correctly in the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=400
```

Answer (score 0):

A timeout of 105 seconds is more than enough. You should never have the need to change it.

If you are not getting the search results in that time, check if your search column is being indexed properly.

Also, check if the column being searched for has the right datatype. For example, the Text datatype allows you to split words before indexing that column. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html

You can even adjust the text analyzer if the default one is not suitable. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

You can also index but not store some long columns. Those columns will be used in search but will not appear in the search results.

For further discussion, you need to share your document structure (including where those columns are stored or indexed or both).

Another speedup possible is to return only desired columns in your search results. By default, it will return all columns which can take time if some of the columns are long. If you have the need to get all the records, minimising this will help you even if there are many records.

Another speedup possible is to paginate your search results. Instead of getting all records together, consider getting X results at a time where X can be configurable with a value of 10/20/50/100/200/500 results at a time.

The properties you have mentioned are related to hibernate. I think they may not help you in elasticsearch.